# How can I use a viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC to show a calculated field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I want to show a calculated field in a view, so I tried to create a viewmodel like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;    

namespace Facturacion.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int testId { get; set; }    

        [Required]
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }    

    public class TestViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int testId { get; set; }
        public Test test { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal calculated { get; set; }    

        public TestViewModel(Test test)
        {
            Test = test;
            calculated = Test.price * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

It gave me an error so I changed the constructor:

```
        public TestViewModel(Test test)
        {
            var foo = test;
            calculated = foo.price * 2;
        }
```

But now when I build the project, it creates a table called "TestViewModels", so I can not reach the data in the Tests table.

I think a viewmodel shouldn't have an id, but if it does not the scaffolder won't generate the controllers.

What is the correct way to use a viewmodel to show a calculated field in a view?

Comment: You view model should not contain `Test test` and all view models need a parameterless constructor or they will not bind on post back. Your view models should also be in a separate folder (say "ViewModels"). In your controller method you get the data model,  initialize a new instance of the view model and map the data model properties to it, then return the view model to the view.

Comment: And _"It gave me an error"_ - what error?

Comment: The error said models.Test is a type but it's used like a variable

Comment: That's because of the line `Test = test;`. `Test` (capital T) is a type - the property in your model is `test` (lowercase)

Comment: I already created a new class in the ViewModels folder, but it still creates a new table in the database

Comment: Remove the `[Key]` attribute

Comment: It won't generate the controller. I'll try generating the controller manually, and later I will tell you what happened.

Comment: What controller? You may to be confused what a view model is - it is not associated with EF. If you have a controller for `Test` and a method (say) `Details()`, then in that method you get the instance of the data model - e.g. `db.Test.Where(..`, then initialize a new `TestViewModel`, set its properties and return the view model to the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77699/discussion-between-allfarid-morales-garcia-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 3):

I could solve it without using the viewmodel

```
namespace Facturacion.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int testId { get; set; }    

        [Required]
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public decimal calculated
        {
            get
            {
                return (decimal)(price*2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the calculated field does not have a set method.

Comment: Your model is part of your business layer, so adding the property like you did here is the right way as the calculation is business logic, not UI.